How to set apps which are not set to "keep in dock" automatically dismissed from Dock when they are closed
This is my dock. I set all of them to "keep in dock", except Adobe Read (the red, bottom one). When I quit it, it stays in dock.
I find it a bit annoying. Is there a way to make it automatically dismiss from dock when it's closed?


Right now it still seems to be running. Can you pull it above the small horizontal line and then quit it?

As nohillside has pointed out, Adobe Reader is still running, that's what the dot next to its icon in the Dock means. Note that simply closing all app windows doesn't always quit an app, to be certain that that's the case, press Command-Q. Also, disable "Show suggested and recent apps in Dock" in System Settings > Desktop & Dock.

@nohillside ah sorry, incorrect/confusing screenshot.

In settings, you can customize the recent apps if you don’t wish to see them.

https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/open-apps-from-the-dock-mh35859/mac

In the customize section, look for this text or similar localized wording if you aren’t showing English: Show suggested and recent apps in Dock

Ah this is the one. Thank you :)
